# Script taking long time to run due to multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, fetch-api

I am running three API requests and they are making my JS script very slow.

The goal is to fetch data from the API and push it my database.

First two API is called using `date` and `next_page_token`. So until there is a next page token I keep calling these two APIs. I call them recursively.

I store the id that I get from above in an array and pass it to the next two APIs.

The last API call run in a loop. I loop through the ids and call the API each time.

Code:

```
export async function getFirstAPI(access_token, start, end, globalObject){
       let url = 'baseAPI/meetings/from=start/to=end/next_page_token=globalObject.next_page_token';
        var obj = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer {yourtokenhere}'
            }
         }

     let response = await fetch(url, obj)
     let data = await response.json()

     return data
}

export async function getSecondAPI(access_token, start, end, globalObject){
       let url = 'baseAPI/chats/from=start/to=end/next_page_token=globalObject.next_page_token';
        var obj = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer {yourtokenhere}'
            }
         }

     let response = await fetch(url, obj)
     let data = await response.json()

     return data
}

export async function getThirdAPI(access_token, id_array, globalObject){

 for(let i=0; i<id_array.length; i++){
       let url = 'baseAPI/participants/{id}';
        var obj = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer {yourtokenhere}'
            }
         }

     let response = await fetch(url, obj)
     let data = await response.json()
     globalObject.store_data.push(data)
   }

 return globalObject
 
}
```

When I run the above for a single day. That alone takes 14min 20sec. If I run it for a wider date range I am guessing this will go on for hours!

Is there a way I can optimize this code? Or is it supposed to take this much time to run?

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Test the api call in postman or browser, check the response time there.

Comment: The `start` and `end` values, along with the `next_page_token`, are not going to be interpolated into your URL values. The URL will literally contain `from=start` etc. Use template string syntax to do what you want.

Comment: @Pointy yea i know. Please ignore the syntax. I just typed it out in a hurry. syntax is not the issue. Time it takes to run is.

Comment: We have no idea how much time a request against an API on your premises is "supposed to take". For all we know the server is running on an old Pentium with 16 MB RAM connected to the network using an old 56k modem. So yeah, that's gonna take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch from `await` in your loop to `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`. It will work much faster. Await is not a silver bullet. It helps but in your case you are waiting for a response on each iteration instead of.. something like "fire all and collect results"

```
export async function getThirdAPI(access_token, id_array, globalObject) {
  const apiPromises = id_array.map(async (id) => {
    let url = `${baseAPI}/participants/${id}`;
    var obj = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { /* */ },
      authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, obj);
    return await response.json();
  });
  const results = await Promise.all(apiPromises);
  // in case globalObject.store_data is an array
  globalObject.store_data.push(...results);
  return globalObject;
}
```

Comment: "It will work much faster" [citation needed]. While it may reduce some overhead on the client, it doesn't make the server operations any faster, so "much" seems like hyperbole.

Comment: Totally agreed, but it is the most obvious way to speed up the code we were asked about. Well anyway, for some people speed up was "100X times faster", here is a proof :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919686/execute-the-next-function-after-the-previous-asynchronous-function-is-over/72919842#72919842

Comment: Instead of using `.then`, it would be nicer and more in line with the original code that used `async`/`await` if you'd do that here too... `id_array.map(async id => {` and then just `await fetch` etc. as usually. This works since async functions - from the viewpoint of a sync function like `map` - do return promises. Also, the store data can now be pushed in a random order which may not be desired, it would make more sense to return the result and then collect the (ordered!) array of all results from the return value of `await Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, @CherryDT, updated, hope that looks better now

Comment: @Sergey Tried your code but it keeps throwing "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error. But i am not even including the data-type as json. Please help

Comment: Usually that means that the response from server was not json.. Probably some kind of error page, you can open Dev Tools in browser - open network requests (open and initiate/send request so it will be recorded) and check the response that is coming. IF code was working previously - recheck the `url` and `obj` is valid, initially you gave us  code in not very well formatting and something might be missing there

Comment: Updated the code (again...), URL part. Hope that helps. If not - recheck everything i asked and we'll continue